# Have remind send out notifications some days in advance

Tags: syntax, remind

I have been trying to use the Unix program `remind`, and so far I enjoy the flexibility. I have set up this command to warn me of any upcoming reminders:

```
~$ remind -z -k'notify-send "Reminder"  "%s"' .reminders/reminders.rem
```

It works, but for some reason it doesn't respect `remind`'s feature to start warning some days in advance (it does for minutes though), e.g. reminders like this don't provide output to the command listed in the `-k` flag:

```
REM September 28 +5 AT 20:11 +1 Get some foo bar %b
```

At this moment, the above example will only trigger `notify-send` at september 28 one minute before 20:11 (and **not** any other days for some reason). I would like to trigger `notify-send` 5 days in advance (in case of this example), and everyday from that. How do I achieve this? (a different syntax is okay too, but others also didn't achieve what I want)

Comment: I think what you are missing is that I want `remind` to send out a notification. It seems that using a combination of the `-z` and `-k` flags is the way to achieve this. (read up on them if you don't know what they do) Unfortunately, `remind` does not send a signal to the receiving process whenever I combine `-k` with the syntax for sending a reminder some days in advance. I encourage you to try out trying to send stuff from `remind` (using flags like `-z/-k` ) to `notify-send` (or some other program) to see what I mean, if you can reproduce it all.

Comment: (previous commenter deleted all of his remarks about my question being unclear, please anyone let me know if it's too vague)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a big fan of this solution because it seems to require you to put in an unnecessary year part, but at least the remind daemon is triggered some days in advance this way:

```
REM FROM October 14 2018 UNTIL October 17 2018 AT 14:34 MSG get that foobar
```

Or, to give slightly shorter way of triggering the daemon everyday (the `*1` part), starting from a particular date:

```
REM 29 Apr 2021 *1 AT 12:43 MSG Return foobar to store
```